# Script tag in jade template not generating closing tag with Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, pug

I am working through the Getting Mean book and have run into trouble in chapter 8, section 2. The publisher's forums are little help.

Hopefully someone can shed some light as I have no idea why it's not working as the book claims it should.

I believe the problem might be to do with the view that I'm using.

```
    doctype html
    html(ng-app='loc8rApp')
      head
        meta(name='viewport', content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0')
        title= title
        link(rel='stylesheet', href='/bootstrap/css/amelia.bootstrap.css')
        link(rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheets/style.css')
      body
       .navbar.navbar-default.navbar-fixed-top
          .container
            .navbar-header
              a.navbar-brand(href='/') Loc8r
              button.navbar-toggle(type='button', data-toggle='collapse', data-target='#navbar-main')
                span.icon-bar
                span.icon-bar
                span.icon-bar
            #navbar-main.navbar-collapse.collapse
              ul.nav.navbar-nav
                li
                  a(href='/about/') About

        .container
          block content

          footer
            .row
              .col-xs-12
                small &copy; Simon Holmes 2014

        script(src='/angular/angular.js')
        script(src='/angular/loc8rApp.js')
        script(src='/javascripts/jquery-1.11.1.min.js')
        script(src='/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js')
        script(src='/javascripts/validation.js')
```

As it's generating the following html when I load the page:

```
    <script src="/angular/angular.js"><script src="/angular/loc8rApp.js"></script>
    <script src="/javascripts/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/javascripts/validation.js"></script>
```

Which means the loc8rApp.js file seems to be contained in a script tag that isn't being closed.

The error being thrown by the console in chrome when I load the page is:

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module loc8rApp due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'loc8rApp' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
```

Just in case the issue is the Angular controller file (loc8rApp.js), it's here:

```
    angular.module('loc8rApp', []);

    var locationListCtrl = function ($scope) {
        $scope.data = {
            locations: [{
              //location data in here...
            }]
        };
    };

    var ratingStars = function() {
      // other code in here...
    };

    angular
        .module('loc8rApp')
        .controller('locationListCtrl', locationListCtrl)
        .filter('formatDistance', formatDistance)
        .directive('ratingStars', ratingStars);
```

Thanks in advance for anyone who responds! =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the template file,

The line under body (row 9) was incorrectly spaced.

Instead of this:

```
    body
     .navbar.navbar-default.navbar-fixed-top
```

It should have been this:

```
    body
      .navbar.navbar-default.navbar-fixed-top
```

This mistake was in the books github chapter-08 branch repository which i had cloned and used to work through the code taught in the chapter. I've now submitted a pull request to get this fixed so hopefully it doesn't affect too many others.

pr can be found here: https://github.com/simonholmes/getting-MEAN/pulls